# Outlook auto archive - how to change archived file's filename automatically

Tags: microsoft-outlook, microsoft-outlook-2013, autoarchive

I want to set Outlook 2013 to auto archive mails. There is a default file for the .pst file - I'd like to append the date to the archive file because I want to make multiple .pst files based on date.

For example, I want to archive all emails every 3 months, so I would set autoarchive to 90 days, then change the filename to something like archive-{date}.pst.

```
example:
archive-20160131.pst
archive-20160430.pst <- Contains email from 2016-02-01 - 2016-04-30
archive-20160731.pst <- Contains email from 2016-05-01 - 2016-07-31
archive-20161031.pst <- Contains email from 2016-08-01 - 2016-10-31
```

Can this be done through Auto Archive, or do I need to manually rename files after the archiving takes place?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This can't be done using Outlook AutoArchive. You need to rename files manually. If you want to automate this, you'll need to use third-party apps/addins.